# Reading value of an XML node

Tags: c#, xml

i need to get the value of an Node in an XML File.

My XML file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<PRODUCTS>
<IPHONE>
    <NAME>iPhone 5s</NAME>
    <MODEL>5s</MODEL>
    <PRICE>899</PRICE>
    <COLOR>Gold</COLOR>
</IPHONE>
```

I want to get the text (iPhone 5s) from the file. 
I have tried several things I have found on the internet:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    String[][] products = new String[3][];
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    System.Xml.XmlTextReader reader = new System.Xml.XmlTextReader("../XML-Test/Webshop-products.xml");
    while (reader.Read()) {
        if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element)
        {
            if (reader.LocalName.Equals("NAME"))
            {
                //Name of product
                products[i][j] = reader.ReadInnerXml();
                j++;
            }
            if (reader.LocalName.Equals("MODEL"))
            {
                //Model
                products[i][j] = reader.ReadString();
                j++;
            }
            if (reader.LocalName.Equals("PRICE"))
            {
                //Price
                products[i][j] = reader.Value;
                j++;
            }
            if (reader.LocalName.Equals("COLOR"))
            {
                //Color
                products[i][j] = reader.Value;
                j++;
                i++;
            }
        }
    }
    for (int k = 0; k < products.Length; k++)
    {
        for (int l = 0; l < products[k].Length; l++)
        {
            Console.Write(products[k][l]);
        }
    }
}
```

No method seems to work. When i run the project (ASP.NET Project) i get the following error:

> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance to an object

How can i get the values of the nodes?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Linq To Xml.

Assuming you you have other products like `IPHONE` under `PRODUCTS`

```
var products = XDocument.Load(filename).Root
                .Elements()
                .Select(x => new
                {
                    Product = x.Name.LocalName,
                    Name = (string)x.Element("NAME"),
                    Model = (string)x.Element("MODEL"),
                    Price = (decimal)x.Element("PRICE"),
                    Color = (string)x.Element("COLOR")
                })
                .ToList();
```

Comment: Visual Studio tells me: 
'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Xml.Linq.XElement>' has no definition for 'Select'...

Comment: @Hack4Life You need to add `using System.Linq;` to the top of your file.

Comment: Ahh! Great thanks, I've always used `System.Xml.Linq`

Answer (score 0):

You may also want to have a look at the methods given below.

1) [XmlDocument and XmlNode](http://www.csharp-examples.net/xml-nodes-by-name/)

2) [Serialization and Deserialization](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/483055/XML-Serialization-and-Deserialization-Part).

3) [Simplified example of Serialization and Deserialization](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/394133/XML-Serialization-and-Deserialization-in-Csharp)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use Linq to Xml:

```
var xdoc = XDocument.Load("../XML-Test/Webshop-products.xml");
var p = xdoc.Root.Element("IPHONE"); // get first IPHONE from file
if (iPhoneElement == null)
   return; // handle case when there is no IPHONE in xml file

var iPhone = new { 
      Name = (string)p.Element("NAME"),
      Model = (string)p.Element("MODEL"),
      Price = (decimal)p.Element("PRICE"),
      Color = (string)p.Element("COLOR")          
};
```

Then you can use name, model, price or color of `iPhone` object. E.g.

```
iPhone.Name
```

Note - if there is many iPhones in file, you can grab them all:

```
var iPhones = from p in xdoc.Root.Elements("IPHONE")
              select new {
                  Name = (string)p.Element("NAME"),
                  Model = (string)p.Element("MODEL"),
                  Price = (decimal)p.Element("PRICE"),
                  Color = (string)p.Element("COLOR") 
              };
```

Comment: @Hack4Life are you trying to use both approaches at same time?

Comment: Linq was imported successfully. Tried to copy your code and pasted it into my project. 

1) from p in ... p is already decleared in the line above. Visual Studio tells me that there is a conflict with a previous decleration of variable p

2) Yes, there are many iPhones in the file.. So I've copied the second code part. Now Visual Studio tells me that SELECT wasn't found.

Sorry if there are some stupid mistakes but I'm a completely beginner in C#

Comment: @Hack4Life then you already have variable with name `p` defined in scope of your method. Either rename that variable, or use different variable name in query

Comment: ok, now it seems to work! So when there are more iPhone in the list how can I access those element? Is the variable an array?

Comment: How can I see the value of the variable? `Console.WriteLine(iPhones)` seems not to work..

Comment: @Hack4Life use debugger. Set breakpoint after variable assigned and investigate variable value.

Comment: Yeah, I wrote it in the html page with `Response.Write(iPhones);`
The output is now: `System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2[System.Xml.Linq.XElement,<>f__AnonymousType0`4[System.String,System.String,System.Decimal,System.String]]`